# Sequelize — find by exact array of associated objects?

Tags: mysql, associations, sequelize.js

Let's say I have `User` model. It has many-to-may asccociations with `User` model as `Friends` through `UserFriends` table.

```
User = sequelize.define 'User',

  name :
    type         : Sequelize.STRING
    allowNull    : false
    defaultValue : ""

User
.hasMany User,
  as      : "Friends"
  through : "UserFriends"
```

How can I find `User` instance with several particular Users in Friends? For example, if user 1 has friends 3,4,5 and user2 has friends 3,4, I’m searching the way to find user2 by exact friend id's array [3,4].

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
User.find({
  where: ...,
  include: [{
    model: User,
    as: 'Friends',
    where: { id: [3, 4] }
  }]
})
```

If you're on a fairly recent version (pretty sure 2.0-dev12 has this feature), adding `where` condition to the include will create an inner join, which means that it will only return users which have friends with id 3 or 4